# Shift letters in object array in a certain order

Tags: python

I'm trying to create unique [gematria](https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/hebraica/about-gematria) (alphanumerical cipher) how do I achieve this?

The form is as follows:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ


alphabet1 = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3,
    "D": 4,
    "E": 5,
    "F": 6,
    "G": 7,
    "H": 8,
    "I": 9,
    "J": 10,
    "K": 11,
    "L": 12,
    "M": 13,
    "N": 14,
    "O": 15,
    "P": 16,
    "Q": 17,
    "R": 18,
    "S": 19,
    "T": 20,
    "U": 21,
    "V": 22,
    "W": 23,
    "X": 24,
    "Y": 25,
    "Z": 26
}
x=' ';
for i in range(1 + 1):
    for product in itertools.product(alphabet.keys(), repeat=i):
        value = 0
        comb = ""
        for char in product:
            
            print([char],":",(x*1),alphabet[char],",",sep='')
```

im search shift all leters

```
KEY OF THREE (A,D,G) (A=1,D=2,G=3,J=4,M=5,P=6,S=7,V=8,Y=9,B=10,E=11,H=12,K=13,N=14, Q=15,T=16,W=17,Z=18,C=19,F=20,I=21,K=22,N=23,Q=24,T=25,W=26)

KEY OF FIVE (A,F,K) (A=1,F=2,K=3,P=4,U=5,Z=6,E=7,J=8,O=9,T=10,Y=11,D=12,I=13,N=14, S=15,X=16,C=17,H=18,M=19,R=20,W=21,B=22,G=23,L=24,Q=25,V=26)

KEY OF SEVEN (A,H,O) (A=1,H=2,O=3,V=4,C=5,J=6,Q=7,X=8,E=9,L=10,S=11,Z=12,G=13,N=14, U=15,B=16,I=17,P=18,W=19,D=20,K=21,R=22,Y=23,F=24,M=25,T=26)

KEY OF ELEVEN (A,J,S)(A=1,J=2,S=3,B=4,K=5,T=6,C=7,L=8,U=9,D=10,M=11,V=12,E=13,N=14, W=15,F=16,O=17,X=18,G=19,P=20,Y=21,H=22,Q=23,Z=24,I=25,R=26)

KEY OF ELEVEN (A,L,W) (A=1,L=2,W=3,H=4,S=5,D=6,O=7,Z=8,K=9,V=10,G=11,R=12,C=13,N=14, Y=15,J=16,U=17,F=18,Q=19,B=20,M=21,X=22,I=23,T=24,E=25,P=26)
```

It is beyond my power someone would help me and edit the code than thank you so much I have been trying to do this for a few days but nothing works.

Those shifts will be more I basically want to start with the letter A / F / K and create attachments from the lower examples.

Those Gematria will be a lot, so need a script.

I'm search if input and shift 3     `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

output is

```
alphabet1 = {
    "A": 1,
    "D": 2,
    "G": 3,
    "J": 4,
    "M": 5,
    "P": 6,
    "S": 7,
    "V": 8,
    "Y": 9,
    "B": 10,
    "E": 11,
    "H": 12,
    "K": 13,
    "N": 14,
    "Q": 15,
    "T": 16,
    "W": 17,
    "Z": 18,
    "C": 19,
    "F": 20,
    "I": 21,
    "K": 22,
    "N": 23,
    "Q": 24,
    "T": 25,
    "W": 26
}
```

Comment: I tried here
[:: + 1] ext nothing worked it will probably be because I'm a beginner in programming

Comment: sorry you need to be more clear what you are trying to do. What is your desired output? At the moment your code and the print statements don't fit to the data with "KEY OF THREE" etc. Where does this come from? Also all your code does at the moment is looping through the alphabet dict and print each key, value pair

Comment: @YScharf I'm trying to move by a certain length of the letter
start in pozition A+F+K and then gradually takes the letters  in the order in this example 4  I want it to modify the original script object array in the results that are below and since there will be more of them, so they need something that did it automatically
`KEY OF FIVE (A, F, K) (A = 1, F = 2, K = 3, P = 4, U = 5, Z = 6, E = 7, J = 8, O = 9, T = 10 , Y = 11, D = 12, I = 13, N = 14, S = 15, X = 16, C = 17, H = 18, M = 19, R = 20, W = 21, B = 22, G = 23, L = 24, Q = 25, V = 26)`

Comment: @YScharf example I want to use every 4 letters

so they use A = 1, F = 2, K = 3, P = 4, U = 5, Z = 6 and then the rest in the same order    output is this tipe `alphabet1 = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3,
    "D": 4,
    "E": 5,
    "F": 6,
    "G": 7,
    "H": 8,
    "I": 9,
    "J": 10,
    "K": 11,
    "L": 12,
    "M": 13,
    "N": 14,
    "O": 15,
    "P": 16,
    "Q": 17,
    "R": 18,
    "S": 19,
    "T": 20,
    "U": 21,
    "V": 22,
    "W": 23,
    "X": 24,
    "Y": 25,
    "Z": 26
} `

Comment: @YScharf numbers to stay in the same position only what is crossed are the letters of each 3 for example

Comment: you just posted the alphabet again. why? you obviously want to do something with A, F, K, P, U, Z but I have no clue what.

Comment: please edit your question instead of writing that in the comments. Make 3 examples where you show the input and exactly the desired output. maybe it gets more clear then

Comment: Obligatory reminder that Stack Overflow is English-only: this also applies to comments.

Comment: the link in  gematria is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

def gematria(n, alphabet):
    length = len(alphabet)
    ret = {}
    for i in range(length):
        j = i * n % length
        letter = alphabet[j]
        while letter in ret:
            j = (j + 1) % length
            letter = alphabet[j]
        ret[letter] = i + 1
    return ret

print(gematria(5, ascii_uppercase))
print(gematria(7, ascii_uppercase))
print(gematria(9, ascii_uppercase))
print(gematria(13, ascii_uppercase))
```

This gives the following output:

```
{'A': 1, 'F': 2, 'K': 3, 'P': 4, 'U': 5, 'Z': 6, 'E': 7, 'J': 8, 'O': 9, 'T': 10, 'Y': 11, 'D': 12, 'I': 13, 'N': 14, 'S': 15, 'X': 16, 'C': 17, 'H': 18, 'M': 19, 'R': 20, 'W': 21, 'B': 22, 'G': 23, 'L': 24, 'Q': 25, 'V': 26}
{'A': 1, 'H': 2, 'O': 3, 'V': 4, 'C': 5, 'J': 6, 'Q': 7, 'X': 8, 'E': 9, 'L': 10, 'S': 11, 'Z': 12, 'G': 13, 'N': 14, 'U': 15, 'B': 16, 'I': 17, 'P': 18, 'W': 19, 'D': 20, 'K': 21, 'R': 22, 'Y': 23, 'F': 24, 'M': 25, 'T': 26}
{'A': 1, 'J': 2, 'S': 3, 'B': 4, 'K': 5, 'T': 6, 'C': 7, 'L': 8, 'U': 9, 'D': 10, 'M': 11, 'V': 12, 'E': 13, 'N': 14, 'W': 15, 'F': 16, 'O': 17, 'X': 18, 'G': 19, 'P': 20, 'Y': 21, 'H': 22, 'Q': 23, 'Z': 24, 'I': 25, 'R': 26}
{'A': 1, 'N': 2, 'B': 3, 'O': 4, 'C': 5, 'P': 6, 'D': 7, 'Q': 8, 'E': 9, 'R': 10, 'F': 11, 'S': 12, 'G': 13, 'T': 14, 'H': 15, 'U': 16, 'I': 17, 'V': 18, 'J': 19, 'W': 20, 'K': 21, 'X': 22, 'L': 23, 'Y': 24, 'M': 25, 'Z': 26}
```

If a letter is already present in the output dictionary, the algorithm will skip to the next letter in the alphabet. This means it will work for values of `n` which the length of the alphabet is divisible by (e.g. when `n` is 13 the algorithm will produce results for all letters in the alphabet, not just "A" and "N").

Comment: What would you like to happen if `n` is 13?

Comment: Could you give the expected output when `n` is 13?

Comment: I've edited my answer to deal with values of `n` like 13, in the manner you suggested.

Comment: I know this may be annoying

but you could edit it so I can add my own gematria there     `        gematria = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}
        test = list(gematria)
        ret[letter] = [test[i]]`  if nod have same gematria 1-26 it does not work like that

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, sorry...

Comment: I would like to create another gematria storm script but throw a bug out of the range list

Comment: done im solved thanx for you help